# XamlReader parse read only dependency property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dependency-properties

I've a string containing a XAML layout of a Grid containing a UserControl.

The UserControl has a read only DependencyProperty called Code.

I would like to use XamlReader.Parse to deserialize the string in order to get the Grid and its child, but I get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException because the property "Code" has been registered as read only and it can't be modified without an authorization key.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Does your XAML try to set a read-only dependency property? This obviously won't work.

Comment: In my Xaml I've simply defined this <local:MyUserControl Code="1" />

Comment: I create my Xaml layout manually and I set it like that because I need that value for binding. I guess I will have to store it in the Tag property then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a read-only dependency property in XAML like this:

```
<local:MyUserControl Code="1" />
```

If you want to be able to do this, the dependency property should *not* be defined as read-only. This makes no sense.

The above XAML snippet creates an instance of `MyUserControl` and tries to set the `Code` property to "1" and obviously this won't work if `Code` is read-only. You won't even be able to compile this XAML so this is not really related to `XamlReader.Parse`.

Comment: At first it wasn't read only but it should have been, so I changed it. I will store the value in the Tag property and use that for binding. Thanks!